# homework problem about the projective real space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Sorry for ask this problem, but I am very complicated with this problem :/ . My course it´s of topology, the teacher said that we only need the definition of the quotient topology and of $$
P_R^2 
$$
but I do not feel comfortable working with the projective plane, still not, and we've never seen anything more about this. But I can use the theorems of chapter 1 of massey on triangulations, about the Euler characteristic is independent of the triangulation, and so on.
The problem is this :

First let's define a line as a set of the form $$
L_{a,b,c}  = \left\{ {\left[ {x,y,z} \right] \in P_R^2 :ax + by + cz = 0} \right\}
$$
Now let's define an array of lines, as a finite collection of lines $$
\left\{ {L_i } \right\}_{i = 1}^n 
$$
  such that $$
\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {L_i } 
$$
it´s empty
 . A paving of polygons of $$
{P_R^2 }
$$
R is the same definition
of "on triangles", but now you can consider any polygons. Prove
that the Euler characteristic of $$
{P_R^2 }
$$
R can be calculated with any paving
of polygons 
$$
\begin{align*}
  & v - \ell + p  \\ 
   v &= \text{number of vertices}\\
   \ell &= \text{number of sides}\\
   p &= \text{number of polygons}
\end{align*}
$$
How can i prove this? I can use the theorem that the number is independent of the triangulation. It should not be at all difficult, but I'm a little unsure )= in the formalism. I think that I must triangulate each polygon and, and in someway count have v-l + p using the triangles
sorry for the stupid question

Comment: I think your last comment is on the right track.  Pick a polygon and triangulate it.  How do $v$, $l$, and $p$ change?

Comment: I did it! thanks for all